# Sintaxe para uso do INTERVAL

Tags: postgresql

Tenho o seguinte trecho de um CASE no meu SQL

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (tabela01.data_abertura - INTERVAL tabela02.garantia 'month') <= tabela01.data_nf
             THEN 'Dentro do Prazo'
             ELSE 'Fora do Prazo'
        END  AS medicao_garantia
```

... 
Onde:

- data_abertura: Data de início de um atendimento
- data_nf: Data da nota fiscal do produto
- garantia: Quantidade de meses que o produto está em garantia

Tenho que calcular o `INTERVAL`, mas estou errando na sintaxe.

Já tentei:

`INTERVAL(tbl_produto.garantia 'month')`

`INTERVAL 'tbl_produto.garantia month'`

`INTERVAL tbl_produto.garantia 'month'`

Porém sem resultados satisfatórios.

Comment: Qual erro aparece? tente concatenar o valor de garantia com o month, veja se funciona: `INTERVAL tabela02.garantia || ' month'`

Comment: O erro é o famoso `Syntax error`, e sempre é referente ao tabela02.garantia. Tua solução não teve mudanças, continua no Syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Melhor que concatenar strings é fazer aritmética:

```
t1.data_abertura::date - t2.garantia * interval '1 month' <= t1.data_nf
```

O fato de o tipo `interval` poder ser multiplicado dá grande flexibilidade ao processamento de datas no Postgresql:

```
select '2016-08-03'::date + 1.5 * interval '1 day';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 2016-08-04 12:00:00
```

Comment: Muito útil e funcionou. Mas é usado quando eu sei qual unidade eu vou acrescer / decrescer da data com o `INTERVAL`. Se eu não sei, não tem jeito. Mas marquei como resposta certa pelo fato da flexibilidade.

Answer (score 1):

Minha pergunta foi resolvida da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN (tabela01.data_abertura::date - (tabela02.garantia || 'month')::interval) <= tabela01.data_nf
             THEN 'Dentro do Prazo'
             ELSE 'Fora do Prazo'
        END  AS medicao_garantia
```